# UIImagePickerView blank images?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am instantiating a UIImagePicker like so:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[self.picker setDelegate:self];
[self.picker UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[myVC presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And for some reason, it doesn't ask me for permission to view my images (on device, it is magically already allowed access (checked in Privacy settings)) and the images are blank. Yes, you heard correctly. Blank. They're completely white. However when I tap in a location where a image should be present, it shows the image in the editor view and displays the image.

Comment: You're setting your source type to camera. Are you saying it actually shows you the photo library with some blank images instead of starting the camera?

Comment: Side note - why are you casting `self` to `id` when setting the delegate. You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @BlackRider, sorry, I'm using both the camera and the gallary in the app. and I copied the code for Camera inadvertently. The camera works fine.

Comment: @rmaddy because it'll give me a warning otherwise "Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'"

Comment: Then fix the problem correctly. Your class needs to conform to those two protocols.

Comment: What @rmaddy means is your view controller needs to also implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol in order to act as the image picker delegate. It's a very common mistake to omit it.

Comment: @rmaddy Done. Same strange functionality. Although, now it does ask for Permission to view my images.

Comment: It doesn't matter where I call this code in my app. Could this be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, this issue had nothing to do with NavigationControllers, UIImages/ImageViews or even ViewControllers. I had a category on NSDictionary that overrode objectForKeyedSubscript. I guess users images are stored or retrieved in a Dictionary and when they tried to index into it for the UIImage, it failed somehow. Or maybe pulled a path that was nil.

The moral of this story is, BEWARE the CATEGORY.

Comment: Why did you override `objectForKeyedSubscript:`?

Comment: @cbh2000 You don't want to know.

Comment: Fair enough.  The REAL moral of the story is: don't modify built-in methods to behave differently.